# Does Xcode 7.3.1 run on macOS High Sierra (10.13)?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, macos-high-sierra

Although I know that this Xcode version is quite old, my company's project still needs to use it and I didn't manage to make it ran properly on my company's mac.

Does anyone have faced this issue as well? Any idea would be very helpful!

ps. On my personal mac, with macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 Beta (17B25c), every time that I try to open Xcode 7.3.1, it crashes and doesn't even inform the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works on my machine... I know that doesn't help you but I just installed it and it opens ok. Maybe upgrade to full version?

[image]

Comment: Hi, are you able to build and run the simulator ios8 using xcode 7.3.1 ?

Answer (score 3):

After running Xcode 7.3.1 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13 VM, I can confirm that I can compile and run build on Simulator and devices with iOS6 & iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no Cross-Compability-Guide to downgrade to older Development Environment or generell Software on newer Mac, because only minimum Requirements are listed in wikis like this:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

So, my tip on this topic is really to use older Hardware to test on matching Environments or try Virtualisation such as Parallels, Fusion or Virtualbox.There are differents in Virtualisation too. If some Virtualisation fails e.g. Virtualbox, maybe another Program (e.v. Parallels) does the job well.

I really use older Mac Hardware for testing older Software-Versions and that is the best tip I can give you on this topic. So its a good idea to have an older Hardware Repository to do this jobs, on which virtualization fails.

I know some Apple Developer which use some older Mac minis in their basement - remote connected - to solve problems like this.